# Applying Dark theme to Ionic App does not make any changes to style of ionic components

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

According to the Ionic Framework documentation, it states in the dark mode that in order to apply dark themes, you simply have to copy and paste the dark theme code that Ionic has provided that can be seen here
https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/dark-mode#ionic-dark-theme

```
/*
 * Dark Colors
 * -------------------------------------------
 */

body.dark {
  --ion-color-primary: #428cff;
  --ion-color-primary-rgb: 66,140,255;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-primary-shade: #3a7be0;
  --ion-color-primary-tint: #5598ff;

  --ion-color-secondary: #50c8ff;
  --ion-color-secondary-rgb: 80,200,255;
  --ion-color-secondary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-secondary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-secondary-shade: #46b0e0;
  --ion-color-secondary-tint: #62ceff;

  --ion-color-tertiary: #6a64ff;
  --ion-color-tertiary-rgb: 106,100,255;
  --ion-color-tertiary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-tertiary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-tertiary-shade: #5d58e0;
  --ion-color-tertiary-tint: #7974ff;

  --ion-color-success: #2fdf75;
  --ion-color-success-rgb: 47,223,117;
  --ion-color-success-contrast: #000000;
  --ion-color-success-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
  --ion-color-success-shade: #29c467;
  --ion-color-success-tint: #44e283;

  --ion-color-warning: #ffd534;
  --ion-color-warning-rgb: 255,213,52;
  --ion-color-warning-contrast: #000000;
  --ion-color-warning-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
  --ion-color-warning-shade: #e0bb2e;
  --ion-color-warning-tint: #ffd948;

  --ion-color-danger: #ff4961;
  --ion-color-danger-rgb: 255,73,97;
  --ion-color-danger-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-danger-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-danger-shade: #e04055;
  --ion-color-danger-tint: #ff5b71;

  --ion-color-dark: #f4f5f8;
  --ion-color-dark-rgb: 244,245,248;
  --ion-color-dark-contrast: #000000;
  --ion-color-dark-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
  --ion-color-dark-shade: #d7d8da;
  --ion-color-dark-tint: #f5f6f9;

  --ion-color-medium: #989aa2;
  --ion-color-medium-rgb: 152,154,162;
  --ion-color-medium-contrast: #000000;
  --ion-color-medium-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
  --ion-color-medium-shade: #86888f;
  --ion-color-medium-tint: #a2a4ab;

  --ion-color-light: #222428;
  --ion-color-light-rgb: 34,36,40;
  --ion-color-light-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-light-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-light-shade: #1e2023;
  --ion-color-light-tint: #383a3e;
}

/*
 * iOS Dark Theme
 * -------------------------------------------
 */

.ios body.dark {
  --ion-background-color: #000000;
  --ion-background-color-rgb: 0,0,0;

  --ion-text-color: #ffffff;
  --ion-text-color-rgb: 255,255,255;

  --ion-color-step-50: #0d0d0d;
  --ion-color-step-100: #1a1a1a;
  --ion-color-step-150: #262626;
  --ion-color-step-200: #333333;
  --ion-color-step-250: #404040;
  --ion-color-step-300: #4d4d4d;
  --ion-color-step-350: #595959;
  --ion-color-step-400: #666666;
  --ion-color-step-450: #737373;
  --ion-color-step-500: #808080;
  --ion-color-step-550: #8c8c8c;
  --ion-color-step-600: #999999;
  --ion-color-step-650: #a6a6a6;
  --ion-color-step-700: #b3b3b3;
  --ion-color-step-750: #bfbfbf;
  --ion-color-step-800: #cccccc;
  --ion-color-step-850: #d9d9d9;
  --ion-color-step-900: #e6e6e6;
  --ion-color-step-950: #f2f2f2;

  --ion-item-background: #000000;

  --ion-card-background: #1c1c1d;
}

.ios body.dark ion-modal {
  --ion-background-color: var(--ion-color-step-100);
  --ion-toolbar-background: var(--ion-color-step-150);
  --ion-toolbar-border-color: var(--ion-color-step-250);
  --ion-item-background: var(--ion-color-step-150);
}


/*
 * Material Design Dark Theme
 * -------------------------------------------
 */

.md body.dark {
  --ion-background-color: #121212;
  --ion-background-color-rgb: 18,18,18;

  --ion-text-color: #ffffff;
  --ion-text-color-rgb: 255,255,255;

  --ion-border-color: #222222;

  --ion-color-step-50: #1e1e1e;
  --ion-color-step-100: #2a2a2a;
  --ion-color-step-150: #363636;
  --ion-color-step-200: #414141;
  --ion-color-step-250: #4d4d4d;
  --ion-color-step-300: #595959;
  --ion-color-step-350: #656565;
  --ion-color-step-400: #717171;
  --ion-color-step-450: #7d7d7d;
  --ion-color-step-500: #898989;
  --ion-color-step-550: #949494;
  --ion-color-step-600: #a0a0a0;
  --ion-color-step-650: #acacac;
  --ion-color-step-700: #b8b8b8;
  --ion-color-step-750: #c4c4c4;
  --ion-color-step-800: #d0d0d0;
  --ion-color-step-850: #dbdbdb;
  --ion-color-step-900: #e7e7e7;
  --ion-color-step-950: #f3f3f3;

  --ion-item-background: #1e1e1e;

  --ion-toolbar-background: #1f1f1f;

  --ion-tab-bar-background: #1f1f1f;

  --ion-card-background: #1e1e1e;
}
```

So I applied the theme accordingly in my `variables.scss` file. However, I am confused as to
why it doesn't seem to have an effect on my elements?

Like for instance, in the ios and material dark theme, there is a variable declared `--ion-card-background` in which I was expecting that background color to be applied on the card by default for the `<ion-card>` tag.

Version Info of my Ionic Project

```
 Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.13
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.29
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for defaulting to the dark theme

```
:root {
    --ion-color-primary: #428cff;
    --ion-color-primary-rgb: 66,140,255;
    --ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-primary-shade: #3a7be0;
    --ion-color-primary-tint: #5598ff;

    --ion-color-secondary: #50c8ff;
    --ion-color-secondary-rgb: 80,200,255;
    --ion-color-secondary-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-secondary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-secondary-shade: #46b0e0;
    --ion-color-secondary-tint: #62ceff;

    --ion-color-tertiary: #6a64ff;
    --ion-color-tertiary-rgb: 106,100,255;
    --ion-color-tertiary-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-tertiary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-tertiary-shade: #5d58e0;
    --ion-color-tertiary-tint: #7974ff;

    --ion-color-success: #2fdf75;
    --ion-color-success-rgb: 47,223,117;
    --ion-color-success-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-success-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
    --ion-color-success-shade: #29c467;
    --ion-color-success-tint: #44e283;

    --ion-color-warning: #ffd534;
    --ion-color-warning-rgb: 255,213,52;
    --ion-color-warning-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-warning-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
    --ion-color-warning-shade: #e0bb2e;
    --ion-color-warning-tint: #ffd948;

    --ion-color-danger: #ff4961;
    --ion-color-danger-rgb: 255,73,97;
    --ion-color-danger-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-danger-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-danger-shade: #e04055;
    --ion-color-danger-tint: #ff5b71;

    --ion-color-dark: #f4f5f8;
    --ion-color-dark-rgb: 244,245,248;
    --ion-color-dark-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-dark-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
    --ion-color-dark-shade: #d7d8da;
    --ion-color-dark-tint: #f5f6f9;

    --ion-color-medium: #989aa2;
    --ion-color-medium-rgb: 152,154,162;
    --ion-color-medium-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-medium-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
    --ion-color-medium-shade: #86888f;
    --ion-color-medium-tint: #a2a4ab;

    --ion-color-light: #222428;
    --ion-color-light-rgb: 34,36,40;
    --ion-color-light-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-light-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
    --ion-color-light-shade: #1e2023;
    --ion-color-light-tint: #383a3e;
  }

  /*
   * iOS Dark Theme
   * -------------------------------------------
   */

  .ios body {
    --ion-background-color: #000000;
    --ion-background-color-rgb: 0,0,0;

    --ion-text-color: #ffffff;
    --ion-text-color-rgb: 255,255,255;

    --ion-color-step-50: #0d0d0d;
    --ion-color-step-100: #1a1a1a;
    --ion-color-step-150: #262626;
    --ion-color-step-200: #333333;
    --ion-color-step-250: #404040;
    --ion-color-step-300: #4d4d4d;
    --ion-color-step-350: #595959;
    --ion-color-step-400: #666666;
    --ion-color-step-450: #737373;
    --ion-color-step-500: #808080;
    --ion-color-step-550: #8c8c8c;
    --ion-color-step-600: #999999;
    --ion-color-step-650: #a6a6a6;
    --ion-color-step-700: #b3b3b3;
    --ion-color-step-750: #bfbfbf;
    --ion-color-step-800: #cccccc;
    --ion-color-step-850: #d9d9d9;
    --ion-color-step-900: #e6e6e6;
    --ion-color-step-950: #f2f2f2;

    --ion-item-background: #000000;

    --ion-card-background: #1c1c1d;
  }

  .ios ion-modal {
    --ion-background-color: var(--ion-color-step-100);
    --ion-toolbar-background: var(--ion-color-step-150);
    --ion-toolbar-border-color: var(--ion-color-step-250);
  }


  /*
   * Material Design Dark Theme
   * -------------------------------------------
   */

  .md body {
    --ion-background-color: #121212;
    --ion-background-color-rgb: 18,18,18;

    --ion-text-color: #ffffff;
    --ion-text-color-rgb: 255,255,255;

    --ion-border-color: #222222;

    --ion-color-step-50: #1e1e1e;
    --ion-color-step-100: #2a2a2a;
    --ion-color-step-150: #363636;
    --ion-color-step-200: #414141;
    --ion-color-step-250: #4d4d4d;
    --ion-color-step-300: #595959;
    --ion-color-step-350: #656565;
    --ion-color-step-400: #717171;
    --ion-color-step-450: #7d7d7d;
    --ion-color-step-500: #898989;
    --ion-color-step-550: #949494;
    --ion-color-step-600: #a0a0a0;
    --ion-color-step-650: #acacac;
    --ion-color-step-700: #b8b8b8;
    --ion-color-step-750: #c4c4c4;
    --ion-color-step-800: #d0d0d0;
    --ion-color-step-850: #dbdbdb;
    --ion-color-step-900: #e7e7e7;
    --ion-color-step-950: #f3f3f3;

    --ion-item-background: #1e1e1e;

    --ion-toolbar-background: #1f1f1f;

    --ion-tab-bar-background: #1f1f1f;

    --ion-card-background: #1e1e1e;
  }
```

Comment: Didn't work. I realised that it's most likely a bug in Ionic 4 where the background for the ionic components like the cards must be set manually with the "color" variable in the <ion-card> tag. A small price to pay for salvation